# Next 13: how do I fetch data for server components every time there is a request with Urql Graphql

Tags: next.js, graphql, server-side-rendering, urql

I currently have the following server component at the route `/app/account/page.tsx`:

```js
const AccountPage = async () => {
    const username = await getViewer();

    return <AccountView username={username} />;
};
```

I expect `getViewer` to be run every time there is a request. However, this is not the case. When I debug the backend code that is supposed to be hit by `getViewer`, it doesn't get hit when I navigate to `/account`. How can I make it so this server code runs on each request? Note that I can't use the updated fetch API in my case because I'm using a GraphQL API and urql for making requests.

**Edit**: The setup for my urql client and the function used by `getViewer` for using my API is the following:

```js
import { Client, TypedDocumentNode, createClient } from 'urql/core';

const query = async <
    TResponse,
    TVariables extends { [prop: string]: any } = Record<string, unknown>
>(
    queryString: string | DocumentNode | TypedDocumentNode,
    {
        variables,
        client,
        cache
    }: { variables?: TVariables; client?: Client; cache?: RequestCache } = {}
) =>
    await (
        client ??
        createClient({
            url: `/api/graphql`,
            fetchOptions: {
                cache: cache ?? 'no-store'
            },
            requestPolicy: 'network-only',
            fetch
        })
    )
        .query<TResponse>(queryString, variables)
        .toPromise();
```

**Edit2**: Adding more details for anyone trying to reproduce the issue

`getViewer` is as follows:

```js
export const getViewer = async ({
    client,
    cache
}: { client?: Client; cache?: CacheType } = {}) =>
    (await query<{ viewer: string }>(GET_SPELL, { client, cache })).data?.viewer;
```

GraphQL schema:

```
type Query {
    viewer: String
}
```

GraphQL resolver:

```js
const Query = {
    viewer: () => {
        console.log('Hitting the viewer endpoint!');
        return 'Dummy username';
    }
}
```

The GraphQL server gets run from `/pages/api/graphql.ts`, which has the following code:

```js
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-micro';
import Cors from 'micro-cors';
import schema from '../../src/graphql/server/schema';

const cors = Cors();

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
});

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false
    }
};

const startServer = apolloServer.start();

export default cors(async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.end();
        return false;
    }

    await startServer;
    await apolloServer.createHandler({ path: '/api/graphql' })(req, res);
});
```

Next version: 13.0.5.

Urql version: 3.0.3

Hopefully this should be enough information for anyone trying to reproduce the issue.

Comment: "I expect `getViewer` to be run every time there is a request." I would expect that, too. And when I test this same setup you describe I observe exactly this behavior. If you could share more details or a reproducer, that would be helpful.

Comment: @JonathanWieben I added more information. Hopefully this should help reproduce the issue. Conversely, is there any way you can share with me the code that allowed you to get the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I had a few things wrong that had nothing to do with what I thought the problem was.

First, when defining the urql client on the server, you need to have an absolute path. The path I was using, `/api/graphql`, was only realtive and thus failing.

Another error I noticed is that I am using the wrong query. It should have been GET_VIEWER, but was GET_SPELL. I managed to get the expected behavior once I addressed these things.